# Typescript discriminate union where field can be anything but the other discriminant field

Tags: typescript

How do I create a discriminated union where I can check either for a statusCode of '0000' or not '0000', so that the correct object type is used?

```
type Foo = {
  statusCode: '0000',
  something: string
} | {
  statusCode: // any string that is not '0000'
  somethingElse: string
  }
```

Comment: `statusCode: string & {}`

Comment: TS doesn't have negated types so there's no way to write `string & not "0000"`. But is your status code really *any* string?  Are there any constraints?  If it's always four digits, you can represent that as a union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrD51W).  Does that meet your needs?  (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply to notify me)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. This approach is very verbose.

```js
type SuccessResponse = {
  statusCode: '0000';
  data: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  };
};

type ErrorResponse = {
  statusCode: '0001' | '0002' | '0003';
  error: {
    message: string;
  };
};

type Response = SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse;

const response: Response = {
  statusCode: '0000',
  data: {
    id: '123',
    name: 'John Doe',
  },
};

if (response.statusCode === '0000') {
  const successResponse = response as SuccessResponse;
  console.log(successResponse.data.name);
} else {
  const errorResponse = response as ErrorResponse;
  console.log(errorResponse.error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use type branding to make such a type and function checking it

```
type Foo = {
    statusCode: '0000',
    something: string
} | {
    statusCode: string & { _not: '0000' } // any string that is not '0000'
    somethingElse: string
}

function whatFoo(foo: Foo) {
    if (foo.statusCode == '0000') {
        return foo as Extract<Foo, { statusCode: '0000' }>
    } else {
        return foo as Exclude<Foo, { statusCode: '0000' }>
    }
}
// ^?
// function whatFoo(foo: Foo): {
//     statusCode: "0000";
//     something: string;
// } | {
//     statusCode: string & {
//         _not: "0000";
//     };
//     somethingElse: string;
// }
```